# RegExp special characters escape

Tags: javascript, regex

I have messed around with special characters in regular expression for several hours now, and must admit that i give up.

Trying to make a password test function, that test for at least one of the following: lowercase, uppercase, integer and special character.

The special characters are "¤@+-£$!%*#?&().:;,_".

I have used this function to escape them:

```js
//used to escape special characters [¤@+-£$!%*#?&().:;,_]
RegExp.escape = function(str) {
  return String(str).replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
};
```

And tested the regular expression in these two tests:

```js
var pattern1=/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[¤@\+-£\$\!%\*#\?&\(\)\.\:;,_]).{8,}$/g;
var regexVal1=pattern1.test(password);  

var pattern2=new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[¤@\+-£\$\!%\*#\?&\(\)\.\:;,_]).{8,}$","g");
var regexVal2=pattern2.test(password);
```

The results are:

```js
var password="AaBbCcDd";//both regexVal1 and regexVal2 is false
var password="AaBbCcDd90";//both regexVal1 and regexVal2 is true
var password="AaBbCcDd90#¤";//both regexVal1 and regexVal2 is true
```

The result from `var password="AaBbCcDd90";` should be "false"!

The question is: What am i doing wrong??

Comment: Within a character class, you don't need to do as much escaping as you might think. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html

Answer (score 3):

The reason is `-` has special meaning in character class. So `\+-£` inside it means "all characters in table of Unicode codes from '+' up to '£'".

So you need escape '-' there.

And yes, you don't need to escape all other characters there

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[¤@+\-£$!%*#?&().:;,_]).{8,}$/g
```

should be fine for you

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it. Of course i only needed to escape -, but i must admit that i stared me blind on the problem, which happens regularly when i deal with regular expressions. By the way when using "new RegExp()" it should be double escaped.

Comment: You can avoid escaping the `-` by placing it at the beginning of the character class : `[-¤@+£$!%*#?&().:;,_]`

Comment: ...or in the very end. but there will still be probability yet that somebody "just put one more additional character in the list of allowed" and ruins everything again :(

Answer (score 0):

enough you add "\" before "+" and "-";

```
 var Regex1 =^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[¤@\+\-\£\$\!%\*#\?&\(\)\.\:;,_]).{8,}$
```

easy way for test your regular expressions is use this website: https://regex101.com/

this example is also good:

Use RegEx To Test Password Strength In JavaScript

```
var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])))(?=.{6,})");
```

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/05/use-regex-to-test-password-strength-in-javascript/