# When converting an array of random characters into a regexp, how to escape the reserved characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of random characters (can be anything).
I have managed to convert them into a regular expression:

```
var regexMarkers = new RegExp(markers.toString().replace(/,/g, '|'), 'gi');
```

Which is working fine.
The problem is when the array of random characters contains special regex characters like: $
I should treat them as a regular character.

I found this:
[RegExp special characters escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978332/regexp-special-characters-escape)
but could not apply to my situation (I'm beginner, just learning Javascript).

I tried this:

```
let newMarkers = regexMarkers.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
```

but I get an error, that regexMarkers.replace is not a function.
Any suggestions?

Comment: regexMarkers.toString().replace...

Comment: Do that `replace` on the `markers.toString()`, like you did with the `,`->`|` replacement, *before* passing the string into `new RegExp`.

Comment: Why not just use `escape` (and `unescape`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To escape any special characters in regex, you just need to use the `\` escape character before it. That regexp you found does that, you just need to use it on your string as such:

```
var regexMarkers = new RegExp(markers.toString().replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1").replace(/,/g, '|'), 'gi');
```

All that regexp you found does is match those special regex characters and replaces them with `\$1`, with that `$1` representing the special character that it matched.

This makes that line of code a little long so it wouldn't hurt to split it up into multiple lines, but that should solve your problem either way.

Here's my own test of it to make sure it worked:

```
let markers = ['a', 'b', '$', 'c'];
var regexMarkers = new RegExp(markers.toString().replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1").replace(/,/g, '|'), 'gi');
console.log(regexMarkers);
//output: /a|b|\$|c/gi
```

Comment: Thank you, @ethan-reiland, this works. Also thanks for the explanation, I was not sure about the '\\$1' part.